# How do I convert ascii integer to corresponding keypress correctly?

Tags: vb.net, ascii

When I try converting ASCII integers to keys that have more than one character I always get an incorrect result.  A -> z / 0 -> 9 works correctly, but any key press that has more than one character always gives an incorrect result, e.g F1 -> F12 / Numlock 0 -> Numlock 9 / home key etc.

example, ASCII code for `F3` is `114` but when I convert `114` to character it always outputs `R` instead of `F3`

This is something similar to what I have tried:

(It seems useless in this example, but this isn't exactly how I will be using it)

```
Dim bind = "114" '(F3) depending on user input
Dim c As Char = bind 'Convert the ASCII integer(bind) to character(c)
TextBox1.text = c 'which in this case outputs as "r"
```

How do I fix this so that `114 / any other key that has more than one character` will output as `F3 / their correct value`?

**Edit, Updated example:**

This code is for user defined shortcuts which needs to work outside the application, so I was using `GetAsyncKeyState` to determine which ASCII integer was pressed, then using that ASCII integer for the bind, but I need to also then convert that integer into a character (F3 in this case) so the user knows which keybind is currently active.

```
    Do
        ExitLoop = False

        For i = 0 To 255
            result = 0
            result = GetAsyncKeyState(i)
            If result = -32767 Then

                Dim c As Char = Chr(i)      ' Convert ASCII integer to char.
                Bind1.Text = c
                Shortcut1 = i
                ExitLoop = True

            End If
        Next i

    Loop While ExitLoop = False
```

Comment: _114_ is `r` [I believe](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/lowercase-letter-r-minuscule-ascii-code-114.html) as well as being F3.

Comment: Yep, 114 is the `ASCII` code for a lower case r as well. See this image for a full view of the key codes https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/ASCII-Table-wide.svg/1280px-ASCII-Table-wide.svg.png

Comment: Are you saying that they could input 114 and you want to know what the character is for that? Using the same logic on the F3 key? They input a number which would equate to the F3 key?

Comment: Or are you after knowing which key they pressed? Because on that you can relate to `Keys.` like `Keys.F3` which is in fact _114_ in the enum.

Comment: The problem is however is F3 is 2 characters not 1. It's F and 3 and I don't think adding together the Integer values works. You can monitor however key presses and check them against `Keys.`

Comment: Another way to look at it is F3 isn't a character. ASCII is for characters. You would have to monitor the KeyPress event and check what keys been pressed on `e.KeyCode` (I think it is) and compare to `Keys.` collection

Comment: `ASCII code for F3 is 114` no it's not. 114 is "r". `I was using GetAsyncKeyState to determine which ASCII integer was pressed` that's not what it does. This is what you pass [Virtual-Key Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx), not the ASCII code. You can see that the [ASCII codes](http://www.asciitable.com/) don't match the Virtual-Key codes.

Answer (score 1):

The title is a bit misleading, as it's not the right way to solve your problem. You have [GetAsyncKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx) which tells you about the state of the key passed by index according to its [Virtual-Key Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx). The value returned tells us if the key is currently pressed down. From the MSDN page,

> If the most significant bit is set, the key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, the key was pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState.

Since the return value is a `UInt16`, and we want to see if the most significant bit is 1, we will `And` the result with 0xFFFF (in VB, &HFFFF).

The program below will report *all* keys which are currently pressed, and put them together in a message, and put that message in the title bar of the form. Make a new WinForms project, and paste this code. You may need to delete `Dispose` from the code behind the designer. The function `GetVKeyPressed` has a limited number of supported keys, but you can make the required cases according to the Virtual-Key Code page.

```
Public Class Form1
    Implements IDisposable

    Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "User32" (ByVal vKey As Integer) As UInt16

    Private timer As New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf timerCallback, Nothing, -1, -1)

    Private Function GetVKeyPressed(vKey As Integer) As String
        ' see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx
        Select Case vKey
            Case &H30 To &H39 ' 0 to 9
                Return Chr(vKey).ToString()
            Case &H41 To &H5A ' A to Z
                Return Chr(vKey).ToString()
            Case &H70 To &H87
                Return "F" & (vKey - &H70 + 1)
            Case &H1
                Return "LMB"
            Case &H2
                Return "RMB"
            Case Else
                Return "Key not supported yet!"
        End Select
    End Function

    Private Sub timerCallback(state As Object)
        Dim results As New Dictionary(Of Integer, UInt16)()
        For i = 0 To 255
            results.Add(i, GetAsyncKeyState(i))
        Next i
        Dim pressedKeys = String.Join(", ", results.
            Where(Function(kvp) kvp.Value And &HFFFF).
            Select(Function(kvp) GetVKeyPressed(kvp.Key)))
        Try
            Me.Invoke(Sub() Me.Text = pressedKeys)
        Catch ex As ObjectDisposedException
        End Try
        timer.Change(100, -1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        timer.Change(100, -1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
        timer.Change(-1, -1)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
                timer.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I know I am a few months too late, but I just wanted to point out that all `VK_*` Virtual-Key Codes are mapped to the [**`System.Windows.Forms.Keys` enumeration**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx), so it can be used as the parameter type of `GetAsyncKeyState()` for simplicity. :)